# Why stringMatcher works not as expected in Pact Test Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, pact

I have a stringMatcher as following:

```
.stringMatcher("id", "[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}")
```

My provider generates uuid value, but my consumer test fails because it says for example:

```
- "9f28ddbd-2c5c-476e-ac54-3bb99543642e"
+ "8528ddba-2c5c-476e-ac54-3bb99543642e"
```

That means they are not matching.
But I expect, that stringMatcher will test value only by regex, but not assert equal values exactly.

The documentation says:
`stringMatcher  Will match strings using the provided regular expression`

What should I do to fix it and test uuid field by regex, but not value?

More code example:

```
@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)
@PactTestFor(providerName = "MyProviderService")
public class PactTest {

    @Pact(consumer = "MyConsumerService")
    public RequestResponsePact allData(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
        DslPart jsonBody = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .array("content")
                .object()
                .stringMatcher("id", "[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}")
                .stringType("name")
                // more fields
     return builder
            .given("GET ALL DATA")
            .uponReceiving("POST REQUEST")
            .path("/v1/search")
            .method("POST")
            .willRespondWith()
            .status(200)
            .body(jsonBody)
            .toPact();

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "allData")
    void testAllCampaigns(MockServer mockProvider) {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate()
            .postForEntity(mockProvider.getUrl() + "/v1/search",Map.of(), String.class);

        Assertions.assertEquals(response.getStatusCode().value(), 200);
    }
```

Comment: We might need some more information on what you're doing. I'm not really familiar with pact but assuming it uses Java's regex library the values you've provided should match your regex. So either it doesn't use Java's regex lib, the values are wrong (might they include the double quotes shown in the output?) or you're doing something we don't see but that interferes with the matching.

Comment: Btw, this might help: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/issues/564 - you might be using `stringMatcher(...)` in the wrong place

Comment: @Thomas maybe you could help me to rephrase this "I keep falling into the same trap. This is not an issue. JUnit results should be consistent. The actual test should be during the verify phase which works fine. So I'm closing this since it's not an issue.". Because I cannot understand why he closed issue...

Comment: You were also right about quotes... I dont know why it happens.
`body: $.content.0.match.id Expected "683876f1-e47b-4bd4-9b8f-c800439654e5" to match '07dd140a-13aa-4f9f-a04f-3255bcb4cb4'`

Comment: At the same time in my contract generated:  "id": "07dd140a-13aa-4f9f-a04f-3255bcb4cb4"

Comment: Well, I'd interpret "actual test should be during the verify phase" as in you should not include the string matcher into actually executing the test or building the contract/test object but when verifying the test results after the run.

Comment: Is the matcher on a consumer request body or response body? I'm guessing the consumer, because you're saying the test is failing on the consumer side. BTW, I have no idea about what that person is saying in the referenced issue either!

Comment: Do you mean you dont understand my issue? @MatthewFellows